# Empty fields while unmarshalling depending on type

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have the following structs:

```
type Company struct {
    Id           uuid.UUID     `json:"id"`
    Name         string        `json:"name"`
    Presentation string        `json:"presentation"`
    Jobs       []*Job          `json:"jobs"`
}
type Job struct {
    Id          uuid.UUID `json:"id"`
    Title       string    `json:"title"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

When trying to unmarshal a json string that should match this struct hierarchy, some fields are filled in and others not. Mainly the uuid, but I also manage to get the title filled in the Jobs but not the description:

```
func main() {
    s := `{"id": "2cc588a8-087a-4b81-a17f-3c9c35d2e958", "jobs": [{"id": "e1498403-82d8-47a9-b744-96b00c8b91e6", "title": "Qsd", "created_at": "2020-09-07T22:52:22.376857", "updated_at": "2020-09-07T22:52:22.376857", "description": "<p>sd</p>\n"}], "name": "NC", "presentation": "<p>qsdq</p>\n"}`
        var company *Company
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &company)                                                                                            
        log.Printf("%+v\n", company)
        log.Printf("%+v\n", company.Jobs[0])
}
```

I'm not too surprised with the dates requiring a bit more formating but I don't get the inconsistencies on string fields. I have set up the code in the playground so everyone can test for themselves [here](https://play.golang.org/p/VzOYiRJmUlK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real issue is that you are ignoring the error returned from `json.Unmrshal`.  Because you are getting an error, you can't really rely on `&company` - it basically just gave up on it once it ran into an invalid date field, otherwise `Description` would have been fine:

https://play.golang.org/p/pxnIlmlPCq5

Comment: Ok right, it seems it fails on the date parsing and doesn't unmarshal any further. With correct dates everything is unmarshalled. Thanks.